# subprocess call git pull weired, Why "git pull" worked, but "git", "pull" not?

Tags: python, subprocess

worked code:

> subprocess.Popen(['git pull'], ..)

not worked code:

> subprocess.Popen(['git', 'pull'], ..)

stdout show: git command help

Why?

Python2.7 Linux

Comment: Are you sure it's the second piece of code that doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, i am sure.